# list of open conjectures which are solved by students in high-Middle school level or receprocally?

Tags: education, conjectures, open-problem

I know only Snevily's conjecture which it   was [proved in 2009](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11856-011-0040-6) by Bodan Arsovski. and  He was a [high-school student](https://www.imo-official.org/participant_r.aspx?id=9164) at the time., Are there other conjectures which are  solved by students in high school or middle school level ? or Are there proposal conjectures by student in high-middle  school level to be open  ?

Comment: Gauss found (but did not prove) the prime number theorem when he was a $15$-year old high-school student. The students Kayal and Saxena found the AKS Primality Test. Ramanujan discovered for himself "Euler's theorems for the sine and cosine" and many other things as high-scholl student.

Comment: Nice example , it is new at me

Comment: I think , the question is rather about existing and established conjectures , not already established theorems that someone could prove or even new invented conjectures. If I am informed right, the prime number theorem and the ASK primality tests were new conjectures noone could try to prove before. And in Ramanujan's example, this theorem was never actually open.